# Find rows in dataframe that contain words that are bigrams/trigrams

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

This example is for finding bigrams:

Given:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['jobs', 15], ['phone', 14],['pop', 16], ['they_said', 11], ['this_example', 22],['lights', 14]] 

test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Words', 'Freqeuncy']) 

test
```

I'd like to write a query to only find words that are separated by a "_" such that the returning df would look like this:

```
data2 = [['they_said', 11], ['this_example', 22]]

test2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Words', 'Freqeuncy']) 

test2
```

I'm wondering why something like this doesn't work.. data[data['Words'] == (len> 3)]

Answer (score 1):

To use a function you need to use apply:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: len(x['Words']), axis=1)> 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The pandas way of doing it is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['jobs', 15], ['phone', 14],['pop', 16], ['they_said', 11], ['this_example', 22],['lights', 14]] 

test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Words', 'Freqeuncy']) 

test = test[test.Words.str.contains('_')] 

test
```

To do the opposite, you can do:

```
test = test[~test.Words.str.contains('_')]
```